# ClickOnce App: Need to set a global BOOL value for reading

Tags: c#, clickonce

I have a ClickOnce App built in c# that uses RF channels to run some tests. The test sends out 50 packets and tests the quality coming back. The problem I am having is 2 stations using the same channel. There are 10 stations running the same application from a share drive.

I was considering having a table with a bool type where, when station 1 starts running the test and uses channel 11, mark channel 11 in the table as TRUE. If station 2 starts running the test, it will scan the table and make sure to choose a channel that is open. Once the test finishes, the bool value will go back to false.

Is there a better solution than writing back and forth to the database table?

Comment: With synchronization, think about the worst case scenario: Both simultaneously query the table, get `false` and then both run on the same channel. Bonus reading material: [How does locking work in C#?](http://blog.coverity.com/2014/02/12/how-does-locking-work/#.Veno-ZdUXpA)

Comment: This is a complicated version of the classic [producer-consumer problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem).  The main issue that you're going to have is what @theB pointed out:  race conditions that will require some sort of synchronization.  Although the method you suggested can alleviate the issue you potentially will still run into the race condition when both attempt to test at the same time.  If this app has a server-side piece that has multiple test threads you can use a sync construct to make sure 2 threads aren't using the same channel @ the same time.